# Good pattern to select multiple values

Tags: objective-c, oop, design-patterns

I have a method that returns an enum value. That enum value is then used to select an image and a color (in two separate functions). I'm trying to figure out a better way to do this than I already have. Currently, I'm using that enum value as an index to a couple of arrays.

This is the method that gives an enum value based on some logic.

```
-(NSInteger)giveMeAValuePlease {
    if (something)
        return enumValue0;
    else if (somethingElse)
        return enumValue1;
    else
        return enumValue2;
}
```

This is the method that uses the enum value to select an image

```
-(void)methodThatRequiresImage {
    NSInteger imageNeeded = [self giveMeAValuePlease];
    UIImage* imageRequired = [self.imagesArray objectAtIndex:imageNeeded];
}
```

This is the method that uses the enum value to select the color

```
-(void)methodThatRequiresColor {
    NSInteger colorNeeded = [self giveMeAValuePlease];
    UIColor* colorRequired = [self.colorsArray objectAtIndex:colorNeeded];
}
```

While this is not a terrible solution, I feel it is prone to errors in the future if values need to be added/removed. I would appreciate any input on what I currently have.

**UPDATE**

After looking at @mawalker's answer and the associated Javadoc, I decided to try a method similar to that. So what I did was create two classes (as well as maintained the original enum), one to act as the type of enum value and another to store the set of enum values.

This is the class that acts as the type of enum value (which is defined inside the .m file of the container class):

```
@interface MVColorAndFlagName : NSObject {
    NSString* _flagName;
    UIColor* _color;
}

-(instancetype)initWithColor:(UIColor*)color andFlagName:(NSString*)flagName;

@end

@implementation MVColorAndFlagName

-(instancetype)init {
    return nil;
}

-(instancetype)initWithColor:(UIColor *)color andFlagName:(NSString *)flagName {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        if (!color || !flagName) {
            return nil;
        }
        _color = color;
        _flagName = flagName;
    }
    return self;
}

- (UIColor*)color {
    return _color;
}

-(NSString*)flagName {
    return _flagName;
}

@end
```

Then here is the container class' .h:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, StatusColor) {
    Red,
    Orange,
    Yellow,
    Green,
    Purple,

    count //always last element
};

@interface MVStatusColor : NSObject {
    NSArray* statusColors;
}

+(instancetype)sharedInstance;
- (NSString*)flagNameForStatusColor:(StatusColor)statusColor;
- (UIColor*)colorForStatusColor:(StatusColor)statusColor;

@end
```

And the container class' implementation:

```
@implementation MVStatusColor

+(instancetype)sharedInstance {
    static MVStatusColor* statusColorInstance;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        statusColorInstance = [[self alloc] initTheSharedInstance];
    });
    return statusColorInstance;
}

-(instancetype)initTheSharedInstance {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Array of MVColorAndFlagName in same order as StatusColor enum (not including 'None')
        statusColors = @[
                         [[MVColorAndFlagName alloc] initWithColor:[UIColor redColor] andFlagName:kRedFlag],
                         [[MVColorAndFlagName alloc] initWithColor:[UIColor orangeColor] andFlagName:kOrangeFlag],
                         [[MVColorAndFlagName alloc] initWithColor:[UIColor yellowColor] andFlagName:kYellowFlag],
                         [[MVColorAndFlagName alloc] initWithColor:[UIColor greenColor] andFlagName:kGreenFlag],
                         [[MVColorAndFlagName alloc] initWithColor:[UIColor purpleColor] andFlagName:kPurpleFlag]
                         ];
    }
    return self;
}

- (UIColor*)colorForStatusColor:(StatusColor)statusColor {
    if (statusColor >= 0 && statusColor < count)
        return [[statusColors objectAtIndex:statusColor] color];
    else
        return [UIColor clearColor];
}

- (NSString*)flagNameForStatusColor:(StatusColor)statusColor {
    if (statusColor >= 0 && statusColor < count)
        return [[statusColors objectAtIndex:statusColor] flagName];
    else
        return nil;
}

@end
```

I'm not sure if this should update is better or not (although I personally like it better), so I would definitely appreciate any additional input on it. And thank you to everybody who's provided input thus far.

Comment: Is your concern `imagesArray` and `colorsArray` getting out of sync?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: that and the enum used to pick values from them.

Comment: In `giveMeAValuePlease`, storing all possible output values in an array can help you keep track of them. Then you may add methods to add/remove values from that array, and every time you add/remove values you may check if the `imagesArray` and `colorsArray` are in sync (i.e. you add/remove the corresponding entries, if you have to).

Comment: Use keys and dictionaries instead of integers and arrays.

Comment: @Willeke What would be good keys for the dictionaries?

Comment: How are the enum values called?

Comment: @Willeke You mean how are they used after they're received? They're used as indicies into the two different arrays.

Comment: A key is usually a NSString.

Comment: @Willeke: But where would the keys come from? An array of keys? A struct? And if so, how is that any better/different than an enum and arrays?

Answer (score 0):

Java has a nice way of handling this. However it looks like Obj-C doesn't have any such functionality because its enums are NOT classes, they are a 'type', and they can only have a single integer values associated with each enum instance.

Java allows you to store arbitrary values as parameters for enum constructors, This would allow you to form a tight coupling between the enum and instances from set(s) of values. (For example the javadoc example linked shows PLANETS with 2 doubles: mass and radius. The enum class forms a tight association between each 'Planet' and its two values.)

I'll show the Java solution below so you understand what I mean by associating values with an Enum. **(This won't work with Obj-C, just as a 'compare/contrast' example with another language so my explanation is clearer.)**

---

Java example: You can create 'values' as constructor parameters for enum instances. [The Planet Example from the official Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) is an example of this with 2 constructor params.

I 'kinda cheat' with the `Each getValue(String val)` method, because it iteratively goes through each enum instance and does a comparison. A static HashMap would be faster (but not 'as easy'(actually just 'as fast') to implement), but this is fine with me because my enums very rarely have more than 10 or so instances. So the 'inefficiency' is fine for my uses.

Here is an example of how I cheat and have a 'string-> enum' via the `static public Each getValue(String val)` method and 'enum->string' via the `public String getString()` method.

```
public enum Each {
    /** the contract, only one **/
    CONTRACT("contract"),
    /** for each application to be generated **/
    APPLICATION("application"),
    /** for 'null'/'none' **/
    NONE("none");

    static public Each getValue(String val) throws GeneratorException {
        for (Each each : Each.values()) {
            if (each.val.equals(val)) {
                return each;
            }
        }
        throw new GeneratorException("unknown each type" + val);
    }

    private final String val;

    private Each(String val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    public String getString() {
        return val;
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't Objective-C.

Comment: No, it is not, I was just explaining that Obj-C doesn't have the functionality like this that Java has. This is because Java's Enums are 'classes' and not custom 'types' as they are in Obj-C. If you want to have 'convenience methods' that will convert between some input value(s) and Enums, you  will have to write the separate than the Enum itself. (Other than perhaps just making use of the single int value you can assign an Obj-C enum instance.)

Comment: The question in in Objective-C. How is this a usefull answer? And I don't know Swift but this solution looks too compicated.

Comment: I consider this a useful answer because it gives compare/contrast with approaches that other languages provide. And explains why you can't use this approach in Obj-C. I find this type of compare/contrast very useful. Sorry you don't. (But my area of study is programming languages and design patterns... so it might be targeted more towards CS majors, but *shurgs*)

Comment: @mawalker: I consider it a useful answer too, because it gave me a different way to tackle the problem (which I'm currently exploring and will update when complete). Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

It is best to avoid arrays and indexes and to make things local in some methods. For example:

Enum and properties or ivars:

```
@property (strong) UIImage *catImage, *dogImage, *birdImage;
@property (strong) UIColor *catColor, *dogColor, *birdColor;

typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, MYAnimal) {
    cat, dog, bird
};

- (MYAnimal)animal {
    if (meows)
        return cat;
    else
        if (barks)
            return dog;
        else
            return bird;
}

- (UIImage *)image {
    MYAnimal animal = [self animal];
    switch (animal) {
        case cat:
            return self.catImage;
        case dog:
            return self.dogImage;
        case bird:
            return self.birdImage;
        default:
            return nil;
    }
}

- (UIColor *)color {
    MYAnimal animal = [self animal];
    switch (animal) {
        case cat:
            return self.catColor;
        case dog:
            return self.dogColor;
        case bird:
            return self.birdColor;
        default:
            return nil;
    }
}

-(void)methodThatRequiresImage {
    UIImage* imageRequired = self.image;
}
```

Dictionaries and keys:

```
@property (strong) NSDictionary *images, *colors;

NSString *const MYCatKey = @"MYCatKey";
NSString *const MYDogKey = @"MYDogKey";
NSString *const MYBirdKey = @"MYBirdKey";

- (void)awakeFromSomething {    // or init…
    self.images = @{MYCatKey: catImage,
                    MYDogKey: dogImage,
                    MYBirdKey: birdImage};
    self.colors = @{MYCatKey: catColor,
                    MYDogKey: dogColor,
                    MYBirdKey: birdColor};
}

- (NSString *)animal {
    if (meows)
        return MYCatKey;
    else
        if (barks)
            return MYDogKey;
        else
            return MYBirdKey;
}

- (UIImage *)image
{
    NSString *animal = [self animal];
    return [self.images objectForKey:animal];
}

- (UIColor *)color
{
    NSString *animal = [self animal];
    return [self.colors objectForKey:animal];
}

-(void)methodThatRequiresImage {
    UIImage* imageRequired = self.image;
}
```

Comment: Where are `meows` and `barks` defined? And how is using an integer to select a key for a dictionary any better than an integer as an index into an array?

Comment: `meows` and `barks` are the same as `something` and `somethingElse` in the question, just some condition. In the first example the properties were missing. I need to copy more carefully.

Comment: Ok, I missed that comparison, but that makes sense.